# How to move file in opt folder to opt subfolder with same name

Tags: macos, terminal, docker

I am trying to install Navidrome on macOS based on instructions here: https://www.navidrome.org/docs/installation/macos/
Note: I have Docker installed but the instructions are unclear if I should install it through Docker or the binary - I don't even know if Docker uses an internal terminal like in the tutorial or if I just use Terminal in macOS. I know even less how to use Navidrome after installing it, like changing my music directory or opening the GUI. But that's not my immediate problem.

I tried to follow the three steps listed first with 1. extracting the binary to /usr/local/opt/navidrome/, but I ended up copying the Unix executable file to the opt folder and not the navidrome subfolder. I can't even see the navidrome subfolder but I can cd to it. Any attempts with sudo to move navidrome the file to navidrome the subfolder say things like "No such file or directory" or "Read-only file system". I guess my real question is I don't know which working directory to use to move the file one folder down. Example using navidrome as my cd:

```
MacBook-Pro:opt me$ sudo mkdir navidrome
mkdir: navidrome: File exists
MacBook-Pro:opt me$ sudo mkdir /navidrome
mkdir: /navidrome: Read-only file system
MacBook-Pro:opt me$ sudo mkdir /navidrome/
Password:
mkdir: /navidrome/: Read-only file system
MacBook-Pro:opt me$ sudo mv navidrome.exe /navidrome
mv: rename navidrome.exe to /navidrome: No such file or directory
```

So what do I use for my cd (opt, navidrome, or somewhere else) and where do I use brackets to distinguish files from folders?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you cannot have a file and a directory with the same name. So if you start with a file named navidrome you have to rename to to a temporary name so that you can create the directory navidrome. Then move the temporary renamed file into the directory with its correct name.

```
cd /opt
sudo mv navidrome n.tmp 
sudo mkdir navidrome
sudo mv n.tmp navidrome/navidrome
```

Now proceed with step 2 of the instructions.

Comment: I don't see a difference in the opt folder. What does n.tmp do?

Comment: @qu4ntumrush that‘s just a temporary filename. You now should have an /opt/navidrom directory which contains the navidrom binary. If this is not the case, please run `ls -al /opt /opt/navidrom` and edit the question to add the output as text.

Answer (score -1):

I just deleted the exe and was able to install and use the program by adding files to the root folder, no need for opt.